# How to calculate this multi-integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Please calculate $$I=\int_0^1 dx \int_0^x dy \int_0^y \frac{\sin z}{(1-z)^2}dz$$

Any hints? Thank you!

Comment: Apply Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: Is this any different from $\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^y {\sin (z) \over (1-z^2)} dxdydz$ ? Or are you having trouble algebraically ?

Comment: @sizz,@hyg17. Thank you very much! Now I realized that it could be transformed to $\int_0^1 \frac{sin(z)}{(1-z)^2}dz\int_z^1 dy\int_y^1 dx$, just rewrite the domain of the integral, and it could be calculated. But how does the Fubuni Theorem work?

Answer (score 1):

The integral $$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(z)}{(1-z)^2}dz\int_z^1 dy\int_y^1 dx\\=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(z)}{(1-z)^2}dz\int_z^1(1-y)dy\\=
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}\sin(z)dz=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(1)$$

Comment: The sign is wrong. The last integral should be +1/2 sin(z).

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue Thank you. :)